# trino sql group by and sort semantic versioning data

Tags: sql, presto, semantic-versioning, trino

I am trying to run a following query in `trino` engine to group data by certain fields and get recent `version` value for that group.

The `version` field is of `varchar` datatype.

A resultset eg.

```
appid    p  version
___________________________
4ef36d   1  3.4.0-mvn.1
4ef36d   1  3.4.0-beta.1
4ef36d   1  3.4.0
4ef36d   1  3.3.7-beta-1
4ef36d   1  3.3.7
4ef36d   1  3.3.5
```

I tried using `max` agg. function to do the job but this only evaluates the values in alphabetic order and length, hence gives `3.4.0-mvn.1` as the recent one.

```
select appid, p,max(version) as latest_version
FROM session
WHERE appid = '4ef36d'
    AND platform = 1
group by appid, p
```

Output:

```
appid   p   latest_version
-------------------------------
4ef36d  1   3.4.0-mvn.1
```

Is there any way I can handle/sort these `semantic versions`?

Comment: There is no build in function (AFAIK) and you will need either to parse version via SQL or create a [plugin function](https://trino.io/docs/current/develop/functions.html) which will compare two versions.